# subset data frame with R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

If we take some example data, we can obtain various outputs as follows

```
A <- (1:10)
B <- (20:29)
df1 <- data.frame(A,B)
D <- c(1,2,3,3)
# with this command, output the first, second, third and third row
df1[D,]

D <- c(5,7,3,3)
# and here the 5th, 7th ....
df1[D,]
```

But I want to obtain a second data frame where the `D` values correspond to an equivalent `A`

```
# here we reomve the first two rows of data
df2 <- df1[-c(1,2),]
# now we want to call upon our D and obtain a new data frame with 
# A==5,A==7, and 2x A==3
df2[match(df2$A==D),]
```

If I use this, I do not get the repeated values

```
df2[(df2$A %in% D),]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `match` argument is not correct

```
df2[match(D,df2$A),]
#   A  B
#5   5 24
#7   7 26
#3   3 22
#3.1 3 22
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really shure, but do you want a data set like this:

```
 A <- (1:10)
 B <- (20:29)
 D <- c(1,2,3,3)
 df1 <- data.frame(A,B)

 df2<-df1[df1$A%in%D,]
```

However I don't understand why you remove the first 2 rows.